# Pythonic way to create single "sorted" generator of two different sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I would like to create **generator** that would output two sequences merged into one. Output of such generator must be sorted (each new generated number is larger than the previous one).

This is my solution that works, but I was wondering if there is more pythonic way to do this.

*(Solution must be generator, not list.)*

```
def generator_two_ordered_sequences(maxnumber, increment1, increment2):
    i = 1
    while i < maxnumber:
        i += 1
        if i % increment1 == 0 or i % increment2 == 0:
            yield i
```

Example usage. Sequence of number 5 and number 17 up to 60:

```
print(list(generator_two_ordered_sequences(60,5,17)))
[5, 10, 15, 17, 20, 25, 30, 34, 35, 40, 45, 50, 51, 55, 60]
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to improve? What is unpythonic about this?

Comment: What two sequences are you talking about? This produces a single sequence from scratch based on multiple *constraints*.

Comment: I would just do `for i in range(maxnumber)` instead of a while loop, otherwise, this seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : I started learning python, so I can't really tell myself what is pythonic and what is not pythonic. I just want to avoid writing python code in a weird way.

Comment: @Pepík well, pretty much, if you are every writing a while loop that simply stops at some end point and increments by some constant step, then you shouldn't use a while-loop. but otherwise this is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the work necessary for this is already done by `range` and `filter`.

```
def generator(maxnumber, increment1, increment2):     
    def predicate(x):
        return x % increment1 == 0 or x % increment2 == 0
    return filter(predicate, range(1, maxnumber))
```

This is easily generalizable to an arbitrary number of increments:

```
def generator(maxnumber, *increments):     
    def predicate(x):
        return any(x % incr == 0 for incr in increments)
    return filter(predicate, range(1, maxnumber))
```

Since you want to define a generator, there's no need to specify an upper bound right now. You can let the consumer decide when to stop.

```
from itertools import count, takewhile


def generator(*increments):
    def predicate(x):
        return any(x % incr == 0 for incr in increments)
    return filter(predicate, count(1))


print(list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 60, generator(5, 17))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say using a for-loop here is more pythonic. So just:

```
def gen(maxnumber, increment1, increment2):
    for i in range(1, maxnumber):
        if i % increment1 == 0 or i % increment2 == 0:
            yield i
```